# Unable to embed templates in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I want to add some content in **Symfony 2**. I do it as follow:

```
{% embed "sub.html.twig" %}
{% block sourcecode %}
    <div class="tab-pane" id="5" name="textsource">
        <textarea id="source" class="span6"></textarea>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

When I run this then it is showing that it is unable to find `sub.html.twig`. What should I do??
And in `sub.html.twig` I am using the following code:

```
{% embed 'AcmeTaskBundle:Default:index.html.twig' with {} %}
```

Comment: Have you tried to read documentation on the `embed`? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

Comment: yeah i have gone through this. but i am getting the error

Comment: unable to find template sub.html.twig

Answer (score 2):

Please try to change

```
{% embed "sub.html.twig" %}
```

to

```
{% embed "AcmeTaskBundle:Default:sub.html.twig" %}
```